How can i display a same UI(function) component in web page with different data in react application
I had created a animation ui in separate component, i have to send data for both css(animation time),jsx and i have to use that component twice, in my parent component.how can i achieve this?
i tried to send the data as props, but i displays the same data. how do i achieve this with same
component and i don't know how to send data for animation, the code for animation is given below
const Education = () => {

  const circleprops = {
    collegepercents :'65',
    hscpercent:'80'
    
  }

  return (
    <><div>
      <Circlebar circleprops={circleprops.collegepercents}/>
      <div>
        <h1>Veltech Engineering college</h1>
        <h2>Bachelor of Engineering - Mechanical Engineering</h2>
        <h3>CGPA - 6.5</h3>
      </div>
      {<Circlebar circleprops={circleprops}/> }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}


css:

@keyframes animate {
    
    100%{
      stroke-dashoffset:300;
    }
  }


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

To create a reusable component in react follow below steps:
Create a reusable component
: In below example I have created very simple card with title & desc. We are going to use prop to show data in our card so title will be {props.title} and desc will be {props.desc}. Thats all for first step.
import './index.css';

function SimpleCard(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="mainClass">
        <h2 className="titleText">{props.title}</h2>
        <p className="descText">{props.desc}</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default SimpleCard;

Now we are going to import this component where we want to use it : I have simply imported it in App.jsx.
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SimpleCard from './SimpleCard.jsx';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <SimpleCard/>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Now in last step we will change title & desc inside our card component from App.jsx : To do that we will just add title="First Card" & desc="This is our first card" in <SimpleCard/>
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import SimpleCard from './SimpleCard.jsx';

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <SimpleCard title="First Card" desc="This is our first card" />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;

Thats all this is how you create a reusable components and also change its data as per need using props in react js.
